# PHP Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting "PHP Notice:  Undefined index: company" when I run a script, this is the part that is going bad, how can I fix it ?

```
while ($row = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$numer = $row['fonefull']; 

$sql = "SELECT company FROM numeros.portados  WHERE number = '$numer' LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo $sql;
$operadoraResult = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(is_array($operadoraResult))
    $resultcompany = $operadoraResult['company'];
```

Thanks

Comment: The array $operadoraResult does not have an element with the key company.

Comment: You could change `if(is_array($operadoraResult))` to `if(isset($operadoraResult['company']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$operadoraResult can be an empty array if there's no company with the given number.
So there won't be an index 'company'.

Try

```
if(!empty($operadoraResult))
```

Answer (score 0):

Notices are kinda like warnings saying "Hey, this isn't going to cause an issue that will break anything by itself, but you might be making an assumption about a variable that is not true"

Like you may assume that a value actually exists at that index, but if the index doesn't exist you're actually getting back NULL.

You can change whether or not notices are displayed by changing the level of error reporting for php. You can do this by either editing the value of display_errors in your php.ini file or you can change in during runtime using the [error_reporting](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) function.

In this specific case its letting you know that in this line:

```
$resultcompany = $operadoraResult['company'];
```

you are trying to access an element in the array $operadoraResult at the index 'company', but there is no index that exists at 'company'.

Answer (score 0):

The array $operadoraResult does not have an element with the key company.

What happens if you change:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo $sql;
$operadoraResult = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(is_array($operadoraResult))
    $resultcompany = $operadoraResult['company'];
```

into this:

```
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $operadoraResult)
{
    if(is_array($operadoraResult))
        $resultcompany = $operadoraResult['company'];
}
```